# `Map` returns empty object with BabelJS

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to run following code with BabelJs:

```
var m = new Map();
m.set('a', 'b');
m.set('b', 1);
m.set('c', { a: 12 });

console.log(m);
console.log(typeof m);
```

But I get an empty `object` from `babel-node` as a result:

```
{}
object
```

What's the problem?

Comment: this means that map implementation doesn't have any enumerable own properties, nothing more

Comment: @vkurchatkin but it has a different result in Google Chrome developer console

Comment: In Chrome `Map` is native and console support is. Try iojs 2.0.0, you will see the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the problem?

There is no problem. Maps simply don't have own enumerable properties. If your question is why you are seeing `{}` instead of `Map {....}`, that's because your environment doesn't have support for `Map`s yet, hence core-js (which is what Babel uses) polyfills them.

It is not possible (afaik) to override how `console.log` should display a value, hence you are only seeing an empty object. The console just shows you *some* representation of the value, according whatever the browser vendor deemed useful.

---

To make my point clearer, lets have a look what you get for `console.log(document.body)`:

```
> console.log(document.body)
<body class=​"...">​…​</body>​
```

Does this mean `document.body` is a string containing HTML? Of course not. `document.body` is a DOM element. The console just renders its HTML representation because someone thought this would be more helpful than just dumping all the properties of a DOM element.

If you really want to see all the properties of an object, `console.dir` takes you at least one step closer to that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. If you use `iojs` instead of `node`, it works well:

```
babel-node test/t.js
```

And the result would be:

```
object
Map { 'a' => 'b', 'b' => 1, 'c' => { a: 12 } }
```

**Note:** `iojs` installer changes the symlink of `node` to `iojs`.

Comment: So, what exactly *is* the problem? What does this answer mean? Do I have to use io.js instead of Node to make Babel work? Or to be able to use Maps?